# Convert floating point variable to integer?

Tags: bash, floating-point, integer

The shell script shown below will show a warning if the page takes more than 6 seconds to load. The problem is that the `myduration` variable is not an integer. How do I convert it to integer?

```
myduration=$(curl http://192.168.50.1/mantisbt/view.php?id=1 -w %{time_total}) > /dev/null ; \
[[ $myduration -gt 1 ]] && echo "`date +'%y%m%d%H%M%S'
```

It took more than 6 seconds to load the page `http://192.168.50.1/mantisbt/view.php?id=1`

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Assuming $myduration is a decimal or integer

```
$ myduration=6.5
$ myduration=$( printf "%.0f" $myduration )
$ echo $myduration
6
```

Answer (score 7):

You can do this:

```
float=1.23
int=${float%.*}
```

I am using this on bash.

Answer (score 2):

It's not entirely clear, but I *think* you're asking how to convert a floating-point value (`myduration`) to an integer in `bash`. Something like this may help you, depending on which way you want to round your number.

```
#!/bin/bash

floor_val=
ceil_val=

function floor() {
    float_in=$1
    floor_val=${float_in/.*}
}

function ceiling() {
    float_in=$1
    ceil_val=${float_in/.*}
    ceil_val=$((ceil_val+1))
}


float_val=$1
echo Passed in: $float_val
floor $float_val
ceiling $float_val

echo Result of floor: $floor_val
echo Result of ceiling: $ceil_val
```

Example usage:

```
$ ./int.sh 12.345
Passed in: 12.345
Result of floor: 12
Result of ceiling: 13
```

Comment: the ceiling function is actually wrong as <code>./int.sh 12.0</code> will return 13.0 where it should return 12 as per the definition of the ceiling function (smallest integer not less than x)

Answer (score 2):

**Eliminate page contents from the variable:**

When I tried your command, `myduration` contained the HTML contents of the page at the URL I used in my test plus the time value. By adding `-s` to suppress the progress bar and adding `-o /dev/null` to the options for `curl`, I was able to remove the redirect to `/dev/null` and have only the time saved in `myduration`.

Since the value of `myduration` is likely to be short, you can use the technique **`ire_and_curses`** shows which will often yield zero as its result which would be less than the 1 you are testing for (note that your log message says "6 seconds", though).

**Finer resolution:**

If you'd like to have a finer resolution test, you can multiply `myduration` by 1000 using a technique like this:

```
mult1000 () {
    local floor=${1%.*}
    [[ $floor = "0" ]] && floor=''
    local frac='0000'
    [[ $floor != $1 ]] && frac=${1#*.}$frac
    echo ${floor}${frac:0:3}
}
```

*Edit:* This version of `mult1000` properly handles values such as "0.234", "1", "2.", "3.5"
and "6.789". For values with more than three decimal places, the extra digits are truncated without rounding regardless of the value ("1.1119" becomes "1.111").

Your script with the changes I mentioned above and using `mult1000` (with my own example time):

```
myduration=$(curl -s -o /dev/null http://192.168.50.1/mantisbt/view.php?id=1 -w %{time_total}); [[ $(mult1000 $myduration) -gt 3500 ]] && echo "`date +'%y%m%d%H%M%S'` took more than 3.5 seconds to load the page http://192.168.50.1/mantisbt/view.php?id=1 " >> /home/shantanu/speed_report.txt
```

Here it is broken into multiple lines (and simplified) to make it more readable here in this answer:

```
myduration=$(curl -s -o /dev/null http://example.com -w %{time_total})
[[ $(mult1000 $myduration) -gt 3500 ]] &&
  echo "It took more than 3.5 seconds to load thttp://example.com" >> report.txt
```

Comment: That mult1000 function is severely misleading:  $(mult1000 1.2) != "1200".

Comment: It could probably use a better name, but it does work with `mult1000 1.200` as I indicated in my remarks about trailing zeros. If that is needed, it's easy enough to make it work with your example.

Comment: My simplistic function also doesn't properly handle values less than one, such as "0.234"